# Partial Derivative of a vector product

Tags: derivatives, vectors

What is the partial derivative of a dot or a cross vector product?

Comment: This may help partially : 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518385/the-partial-derivative-of-the-cross-product-of-two-vectors

Comment: Partial derivative with respect to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For vector valued function the product rule applies to dot and cross product when the partial derivative is involved.

$$ \frac \partial{\partial x }(f.g) =  f. \left (\frac {\partial g}{\partial x }\right)+ \left (\frac {\partial f}{\partial x }\right).g $$

$$\frac \partial{\partial x } (f\times g) =  f\times \left (\frac {\partial g}{\partial x }\right)+ \left (\frac {\partial f}{\partial x }\right)\times g $$